# Why is maven surefire not even running?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I've been trying to split a repository to run specific tests, and I've had some issues with running the tests due to surefire.

When trying to run anything by even simply calling `mvn test`, it seems like that plugin is not even being accessed. The output ends up as:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building {repository_name} 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.132 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-10T12:07:46-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why would surefire not even start up? What could be wrong with my setup?

This is my plugins section of my POM, where I try to specify the suite to use. I assume that is defined in the command line arguments.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXMLFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>${listener-list}</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess: your `pom.xml` contains `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found was to include the "execution" block onto surefire, so the additional few lines added after the configuration block would be

```
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <id>run-tests</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
         </goals>
     </execution>
 </executions>
```

That fixed surefire not showing, but I'm still having an issue when trying to use my specific suite XML file.

Comment: A guess: your `pom.xml` contains `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

Comment: That's it!!!! I was moving tests from one repository, and copied over the parent pom. That must have caused none of the tests to be picked up. Thank you!!